# A problem setting a value of a class that is being segued to in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, segue

I have 2 view controllers and a segue between them that I trigger programmatically.

The first view controller has some data stored in `self.myCustomProperty` that it needs to pass to the 2nd controller. The second view controller with class name `MyTableViewController`, which inherits from `UITableViewController`, has a property `customData` which implies also the corresponding setter method `setCustomData:somedata`.

The first view controller performs the segue on a certain event:

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"MyCustomSegue" sender:self];
```

which starts this:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if( [segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"MyCustomSegue"] ){
        MyTableViewController *destinationController = segue.destinationViewController;

        [destinationController setCustomData:self.myCustomProperty];
    }
 }
```

The problem is that `[destinationController setCustomData:self.myCustomProperty]` causes:

> 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UITableViewController setCustomData:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x...

After inspecting the problem I noticed that the `destinationController` variable has the class `UIViewController` class instead of `MyTableViewController`. I suppose the exception is thrown because `UIViewController` does not have the `customData` property.

I have searched for some time on the Internet but neither did I find mention of such problems nor did I find a way to turn `UIViewController` into `MyTableViewController`. The only method to do the latter that I have found is `object_setClass(id obj, Class cls)`, but using it can cause serious problems.

How can I solve the issue?

Comment: Set class `MyTableViewController` for yours tableViewController in storyboard.

Answer (score 0):

Your error says:

> 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[**UITableViewController** setCustomData:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x...

Note that the class name in this error message is `UITableViewController`, not the name for your specific class. This is a tell-tale sign that you have neglected to set the base class for your storyboard scene. It's using the default `UITableViewController` rather than your specific subclass. And the base `UITableViewController` obviously doesn't know what to make of the `setCustomData` method.

Set the base class for your storyboard scene, and it should fix the issue.

Comment: Unfortunately, on my target view controller in the identity inspector I have the correct value for "Class" set and the "Inherit Module from Target" is also checked. Actually, when I change the custom class to something else and then type the correct one again and press enter, the "Inherit Module from Target" is not being checked automatically. I have to check it. I don't know if this means anything.
 
Additional info: the segue is presented modally.

Comment: Additional info: the .m file has the correct target set, I cannot set the target at .h file (I guess it's correct)

Comment: Additional Info: when I start entering the target controller's class name in the identity inspector, it is correctly autocompleted.

Comment: That all sounds basically correct (though the “inherit module from target” is weird). So, let’s step back. NSLog (or set breakpoint and examine it in debugger) the `segue.destinationViewController` in `prepareForSegue` and see what class it is. If it’s a `UITableViewController` that means that the segue is going to a `UITableViewController` rather than your subclass. Then you’d focus on that. If it _is_ your subclass, then you might want to step back and look where else you call `setCustomData`...

Comment: It's UITableViewController. How could I focus on that?